# How to clone a specific subdirectory as root in Git?

Tags: git, module, sparse-checkout

I have a library Git repo:

```
Library Root
 ┗ sample
 ┗ lib
 ┗ README.md
```

I want to clone only `lib` directory at the repo to my project like below:

```
Project Root
 ┗ app
 ┗ lib // Cloned from the library repo
 ┗ some files
```

I know about the sparse checkout, but it retains the root directory. For example,

```
Project Root
 ┗ app
 ┗ Library Root
    ┗ lib
 ┗ some files
```

The `lib` at the Library Repo and Project must be able to sync each other

Is there any way to achieve this? Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: You might consider [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: @Todd
But submodules clone `Library Root` not only `lib`

Comment: I resolved it myself via `subtree`